# Share an image to Faceboook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to share an image to facebook. For this I am trying the API call suggested [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo#Creating)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      FB.api(
          "/{page-id}/photos",
          "POST",
          {
              "url": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/images\/fb_icon_325x325.png",
              "published": "false"
          },
          function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
              /* handle the result */
            }
            else
            {
              console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(response))
            }
          }
      );
    } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
  });
```

But I am getting an error `(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {page-id}`
Is page-id the same as the userID returned in the authResponse? Because I also tried hardcoding that id, but I got a deprecated API message.

I need to allow the user to share the photo directly to his feed.

Thanks

Comment: You should most likely use `/me/photos` and the correct access token. But if you got deprecated API message it most likely means the API is deprecated.

Comment: _“I need to allow the user to share the photo directly to his feed.”_ - you can not post to user profiles via API any more, the necessary permissions have been removed. (A page would be a different thing, but your phrasing is ambiguous as to what you actually mean.)

Answer (score 0):

Page ID and User ID are not the same. You get a User ID after authorization, you get a Page ID by using the `/me/accounts` endpoint with a User Token. You can also get Page Tokens with `/me/accounts?fields=access_token`. You need to use a Page Token with the publish_pages and manage_pages permissions to create posts or photos on a Page you manage.

As WizKid commented, you can also just use `/me/photos` to upload photos. Just use a Page Token.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/